# How to avoid sms reaching native inbox for particular app in android

Tags: android

Iam sending GPS data through sms. I am using abortBroadcast and in android manifest android:priority for receiver setted as 1000. So the problem when the app is running mobile not receiving other messages other than app.Please help me.

```
        My code is as follows:


    //This is Broadcast Receiver that I Registered in android manifest.



        public class SimpleSmsReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

             public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  

             if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"))
                 {

                    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                    if (bundle != null) {
                        Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                        SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdusObj.length];
                        for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                        }
                        for (SmsMessage currentMessage : messages) {
                         sender = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                         msg =msg+currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                        }

                        this.abortBroadcast();  
//Here Iam cancelling the broadcast.


            }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Iam searching for string KEY_SENDER in the message if it exists then  I am using abortbroadcast.So the messages with KEY_SENDER as substring will not reach native inbox.so the other messages will be reach to inbox.  



  int intIndex = msg.indexOf("KEY_SENDER");
  if(intIndex == - 1){
  System.out.println("KEY_SENDER not found");
  }

  else
  {
  this.abortBroadcast();
  }
```